# How does wage restriction affect employment in the given scenario?

Tags: macroeconomics

Consider a downward sloping labour demand curve and an upward sloping labour supply curve. If the wage is fixed at $\bar{w} > w^*$ (where $w^*$ is the equilibrium or labour market clearing wage rate), why is it that the fall in employment in this case is same as it would have been if wages were flexible?

As I understand, the employment in the two cases may not necessarily reduce by the same amount.

[image]

The diagram is (hopefully) self-explanatory and the change in employment are given by the (thick) $\color{blue}{\textbf{blue}}$ lines. The two lines are not of equal lengths unless the demand curve is vertical.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You're right. Fall in the equilibrium employment level as a result of left-shift in the demand for labor curve may not be the same in the two scenarios (as your diagram shows).

Comment: @Amit Thank you.